# jQuery last child val() undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.item-checkbox', function () {

    $(this).parent().find('.val-before').val();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="li-14">
    <input class="val-before hidden" type="text" value="checked">
    <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
  </li>
  <li id="li-15">
    <input class="val-before hidden" type="text" value="checked">
    <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
  </li>
</ul>
```

In li-14 or not li-15, val is "checked" or "unchecked"

In li-15, val is undefined

What's wrong?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Your code work http://jsfiddle.net/t7xc3kzr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this problem, not that jQuery css selector does not work, because the element id is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

try with `prev()` function

use `$(this).prev('.val-before').val();` instead of this `$(this).parent().find('.val-before').val();`

```js
$(document).on('change', '.item-checkbox', function() {

  var val = $(this).prev('.val-before').val();
  console.log(val);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>...
    <li id="li-14">
      <input class="val-before hidden" type="text" value="checked">
      <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
    </li>
    <li id="li-15">
      <input class="val-before hidden" type="text" value="checked">
      <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think problem of OP isn't in it and this doesn't helpful because both of `.parent().find('.val-before')` and `.prev('.val-before')` return same element.

Comment: `last child val() undefined` but this answer given value

Comment: No matter which selector the `<input>` element in the last item `<li>` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this,

```js
$('.item-checkbox').on('change', function () {
  if($(this).val() == 'checked'){
    $(this).prev().val('unchecked');
    $(this).val('unchecked');
    console.log($(this).prev().val());
  }
  else {
    $(this).prev().val('checked');
    $(this).val('checked');
    console.log($(this).prev().val());
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="li-14">
<input class="val-before hidden" type="text" value="">
<input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
</li>
<li id="li-15">
<input class="val-before hidden" type="text" value="">
<input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _"Have a look at this"_ is not a proper explanation of the problem and why your solution/answer (should) work.

Comment: Run the code snippet! I provided another workaround for the OP's problem.

Comment: This is still missing an explanation of the problem (which btw. doesn't exist: http://jsfiddle.net/t7xc3kzr/) and your solution.

Comment: Why should I be _"happy"_? I only want you to add some explanation on your answer: _"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. **Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better**."_ (from the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))